# If I have a list of DOM elements that need to be appended, is there a way to combine them first before appending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Given the following code:

```
li = random_object["li_element"] 
other = other_object["p_element"]
...
// I have a bunch of objects above, all of which were initially created and stored as jQuery objects, e.g.,
// random_object["li_element"] = $("<li>test</li>")

$("#target").append(li)
$("#target").append(other)
```

I understand that `.append()` is an expensive method, so I'm wondering is there a way to first combine the elements above, `li` and `other`, in that order, and then append them all at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both in jQuery and when using the DOM directly.

### Using jQuery

You can create a jQuery object using [the signature accepting an array](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray) wrapping those two elements and then append it:

```
$("#target").append($([li[0], other[0]]));
```

The `[0]` there are to put the raw elements, not the jQuery objects, in the array. `$()` accepts an array of DOM elements, but not jQuery objects. If those jQuery objects may have multiple elements in them, you need to do a bit more work. Using ES2015+:

```
$("#target").append($([...li.get(), ...other.get()]));
```

Using ES5 only:

```
var array = li.get();
array.push.apply(array, other.get());
$("#target").append($(array));
```

Live Example:

```js
var li = $("<li>li</li>");
var other = $("<li>other</li>");
$("#target").append($([li[0], other[0]]));
```

```html
<ul id="target"></ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Using the DOM directly

With the DOM, you can create a document fragment and append it:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild(li[0]);
fragment.appendChild(other[0]);
document.getElementById("target").appendChild(fragment);
```

The contents of the fragment are appended, not the fragment itself.

Again the `[0]` are so we access the raw DOM elements instead of the jQuery objects. And again, if there are multiple elements in `li` and/or `other`, you need to handle that:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
li.each(function() {
    fragment.appendChild(this);
});
other.each(function() {
    fragment.appendChild(this);
});
document.getElementById("target").appendChild(fragment);
```

Live Example:

```js
var li = $("<li>li</li>");
var other = $("<li>other</li>");
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild(li[0]);
fragment.appendChild(other[0]);
document.getElementById("target").appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<ul id="target"></ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> I understand that `.append()` is an expensive method

Not especially, but if you had some seriously-performance-critical code and a lot of things to append, building them up in a fragment and then appending the fragment does reduce the overhead.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Comment: @james - Yes, sorry, I was just in the process of updating the answer. I didn't see your comment in the code that `li` and `other` were jQuery objects, I thought they were raw DOM elements. See the updated answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Yes in my case, `append` is expensive, because I have quite a number of them to execute